# What are the latest methods used in Firebase storage with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to get upload status of the files i try to upload it to Firebase Storage. But i think the latest methods to get the status from firbase storage has changed and i unable to find what are the latest methods.
Please help me to resolve this problem

```
uploadToFirebase() {
    String fileName = _path!.split('/').last;
    String filePath = _path!;
    upload(fileName, filePath);
  }

  upload(fileName, filePath) {
    FileType _pickType = FileType.custom;
    _extension = fileName.toString().split('.').last;
    Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    final UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(
      File(filePath),
      SettableMetadata(
        contentType: '$_pickType/$_extension',
      ),
    );
    setState(() {
      _tasks.add(uploadTask);
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    _tasks.forEach((UploadTask task) {
      final Widget tile = UploadTaskListTile(
        task: task,
        onDismissed: () => setState(() => _tasks.remove(task)),
        onDownload: () => downloadFile(task.snapshot.ref),
      );
      children.add(tile);
    });
    return Container();
  }
```

The above code is in a seperate STateful Class

```
class UploadTaskListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const UploadTaskListTile(
      {Key? key, this.task, this.onDismissed, this.onDownload})
      : super(key: key);

  final UploadTask? task;
  final VoidCallback? onDismissed;
  final VoidCallback? onDownload;

  String get status {
    String result;
    if (task!.isComplete) {
      if (task.isSuccessful) {
        result = 'Complete';
      } else if (task.isCanceled) {
        result = 'Canceled';
      } else {
        result = 'Failed ERROR: ${task.lastSnapshot.error}';
      }
    } else if (task.isInProgress) {
      result = 'Uploading';
    } else if (task.isPaused) {
      result = 'Paused';
    }
    return result;
  }

  String _bytesTransferred(StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    return '${snapshot.bytesTransferred}/${snapshot.totalByteCount}';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<StorageTaskEvent>(
      stream: task.events,
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<StorageTaskEvent> asyncSnapshot) {
        Widget subtitle;
        if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
          final StorageTaskEvent event = asyncSnapshot.data;
          final StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;
          subtitle = Text('$status: ${_bytesTransferred(snapshot)} bytes sent');
        } else {
          subtitle = const Text('Starting...');
        }
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key(task.hashCode.toString()),
          onDismissed: (_) => onDismissed(),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Upload Task #${task.hashCode}'),
            subtitle: subtitle,
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Offstage(
                  offstage: !task.isInProgress,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.pause),
                    onPressed: () => task.pause(),
                  ),
                ),
                Offstage(
                  offstage: !task.isPaused,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.file_upload),
                    onPressed: () => task.resume(),
                  ),
                ),
                Offstage(
                  offstage: task.isComplete,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                    onPressed: () => task.cancel(),
                  ),
                ),
                Offstage(
                  offstage: !(task.isComplete && task.isSuccessful),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.file_download),
                    onPressed: onDownload,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Now the problem im facing with the above code is that task.isComplete or task.isProgress is throwing a compile time error where in it says isComplete or isProgress doesnt exist. THen how shall i get the status of upload.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `task!.snapshot.state.success` instead of `task!.isComplete`.
Other values will use same `task!.snapshot.state` but instead use the below chart.

```
paused → Indicates the task has been paused by the user.

running → Indicates the task is currently in-progress.

success → Indicates the task has successfully completed.

canceled → Indicates the task was canceled.

error → Indicates the task failed with an error.
```

Source link [TaskState](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage_platform_interface/latest/firebase_storage_platform_interface/TaskState.html)